# In JSP, how can i check, using JSTL, if certain session attribute exists in request?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, model-view-controller, jstl

This is  code in servlet:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
session.setAttribute("user", user);
```

I am forwarding request to JSP, where i want to check if there is session scoped user parameter attached.

```
<c:if test="${??? - check if user is attached to request}">
/   /message
</c:if>
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
<c:if test="${sessionScope.user != null}">
    There is a user **attribute** in the session
</c:if>
```

Answer (score 10):

I think you mean checking the session scope right?

```
<c:if test="${!empty sessionScope.user}">
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do that by using the following code

Setting session in `Servlet`

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(); 
session.setAttribute("user", user);
```

Access session value by `EL` in `JSP`

```
<p>${sessionScope:user}</p>
```

Checking the session in `JSP` using `JSTL`

```
<c:if test="${sessionScope:user != null}" > 
   session value present......
</c:if>
```